# End of life for LiFePo4 cells

Tags: batteries, lifepo4

Can anybody provide a reliable authoritative reference explaining succinctly why the "Remaining Useful Life" of an LFP cell would be low after capacity retention drops below 80%?

**Background**: I purchased a set of ostensibly new CALB SE200 LFP cells from a seller on AliExpress, but was sent poorly matched cells from multiple manufacturing batches with remaining capacities of between 59 and 79%. I since learned that CALB stopped manufacturing these cells somewhere between 2 and 5 years ago.

I have some traction with AliExpress customer service as part of their dispute process, but I need to demonstrate to them the true severity of the problem, which is proving challenging. At present, they have proposed a partial refund on the basis that they accept my video evidence that the cell capacities are diminished but argue that the cells are still usable. In truth though, these cells are no longer fit for purpose.

I found this article, though it is referring primarily to phone batteries, so is likely to be dismissed as not directly applicable.

https://www.qnovo.com/blogs/what-happens-after-80-percent

Comment: I don't see this as an engineering problem. You're getting scammed twice, by the seller and by Aliexpress support protecting the seller. You have imported electronics waste, and unless they offer to take it back for a full refund and all shipping expenses paid, you will have to tell the import authorities that they are sending dangerous electronics waste to your country. Don't play their game. Also, obviously, this is the last article you ever bought off Aliexpress, right?

Comment: @DKNguyen would you not expect the capacity to drop off much faster below this point though? Also, is there any risk associated with continuing to use them longer term? I know LFP cells are a much lower fire hazard than traditional LiIon cells, but just checking.

Comment: Just convention which a layman probably won't be easily convinced by. Lots of IEEE papers mention it offhand. If you can handle more capacity loss you can keep using them. Similar to how an army is considered annhilated after 30% losses. But yeah, you got scammed which is why you don't buy stuff off AliExpress.

Comment: I've never tried. 80% is used as a general metric for all rechargeable chemistries so that should tell you about how non-rigourous it is. Most applications can't tolerate more loss of performance. I know of no specifics but cannot think of any safety issues. You will probably have reduced power though (different than energy) since a trend is increased impedance. Reduced power here means reduced max current output.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, you are right, it isn't exactly an electrical engineering question as such, but it is related, I figured people in this community would know the answer, and I don't know of a better SE forum for such a question. Also, "Last article from AliExpress"? Certainly the last high value battery, yes. I regularly buy other things there and have mostly had positive results.

Comment: I suppose the best case study is cell phones where a lot of people wear out batteries quickly and continue to try and squeeze life out of them.

Comment: @DKNguyen, thanks, that is a good point about the power output also

Comment: @JohnRix well the engineer's wisdom here is "don't buy at suppliers you can't trust and have no legal recourse against". You have already lost this battle – Aliexpress support is clearly not intending to accept your word that things are useless, and are trying to solve the issue in the best interest of the company, not you. No amount of scientific proof is going to convince them, so your whole technical question is ignoring your situation! If this was a couple hundred € in batteries, cut your losses, and move on. If it's >> 1000€, talk to an attorney specializing in trade with China, I guess?

Comment: (aliexpress has already demonstrated zero interest in retaining you as a customer if you insist on being delivered what you ordered. So, there's no assumption that you can somehow appeal to their honor or quality of customer relations. )

Comment: @MarcusMüller, it was about €1450. So far, I'm being offered about 50% of that back. Am so tired of the whole thing at this point that I'm just about ready to accept that and walk away. Not interested in solicitors

Comment: There's a decent chance they won't know the difference between lithium-polymer, lithium-ion and LiFePO4 batteries, so your chart could work. Maybe they did test phone batteries but it doesn't say it's for phone batteries and it's not like the shape makes a big difference anyway. Another quick idea to consider is a counter offer: you'll walk away if they refund 75%, which it sounds like you'd be not too angry about.

Comment: Aging doesn't accelerate past the 80% point, in fact it gently *decelerates*. So depending on your definition of "useful life" the thing you're trying to prove may not be strictly true. There's plenty of life left *if you're willing to treat them as lower-capacity batteries*. So I would stick to "not fit for purpose" rather than "near end of useful life".

Comment: Thanks @hobbs, that gives me some solace. Along the same lines of the original question then, would you have a reference that supports that, for my own interest?

Comment: @JohnRix just do a search for "lifepo4 calendar aging". Most of the graphs you find won't go below 80% capacity, but a few do, and all of them have a general agreement on the shape of the curve.

Comment: @hobbs, interesting. I would have thought cycle aging would be a more significant factor than calendar aging, but the first paper I read on the subject almost discounts cycle aging as comparatively insignificant in most applications. That's my something new for today so!

Comment: Still seems to be some ongoing interest in this topic from alerts I get from SO. Just for anybody interested in the outcome, I did ultimately get €700 refund from AliEx. I have deployed the batteries in my home and am seeing around 6kWh of capacity as expected from my test results. Not great, but they are working, and at the current daytime electricity prices here (Ireland), I stand to cover the remaining cost of the cells within a year with the way things are going. Result!